# How to make the browser download .csv file from a node / express application

Tags: node.js

In my node /express app I have the following server-side file download function:

```
app.get('/download_playcards_export', function(req, res){

            var file = fs.createReadStream('/Users/eugene/Documents/dev/node/DataManager/PlayCards.csv');
            var stat = fs.statSync('/Users/eugene/Documents/dev/node/DataManager/PlayCards.csv');
            res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
            res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=PlayCards.csv');
            file.pipe(res);
        }
    );
```

I can see the contents of my .csv file on the browser console:

```
$scope.exportPlaycardsData = function(){

                        $http.get('/download_playcards_export').success(function(response) {
                            console.log('success downloading playcards export  ' + response);
                        });
            }
```

But I am unable to make the browser just DOWNLOAD this file.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: When using `$http.get` you'll make an XHR request. Why not simply put a link to the file on your page?

Comment: The reason for me to go with the XHR route is that the csv file is being generated dynamically

Comment: You should still be able to bind the `href` of your link to a dynamically set property provided by your controller. Within your `http.get` callback, it's actually "too late" to perform an attachment-like file download as the content has already been transferred.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a syntax sketch for me to learn from, please?

Comment: `<a href="/download_playcards_export">Download CSV</a>` Keep it simple.

Comment: @EugeneGoldberg If you shouldn't receive a response within the next hours, let me know. I'm currently on the road which makes posting longer answers difficult.

Comment: This worked (in combination with using ng-show). If you post this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept. Thanks!

Comment: This worked. If you'd like to post it as the answer, I'dd be glad to accept it.